# Typescript Express endpoint coverage using mocha and supertest

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, integration-testing, code-coverage

I have an express App I implemented unit tests using mocha+chai+supertest and I cant seem to find how to get a code coverage report, I used nyc in the past but never did it for endpoints.

basically I want to see which routes did I cover.

I read about `istanbul-middleware` and I noticed it hasn't been updated or maintained since 2015.
What I want to achieve is a table just like nyc outputs that displays a list of routes my API has and which routes are covered by unit tests

how can I achieve this?